# SQL to return a single value when two are sometimes present

Tags: sql, oracle

Very much a beginner with SQL

My table contains access requirements, with two types being held all in the same table.
A record can have either **'ADP'** or **'SENT'** or **Both**.
I need to return a single value to feed to another query.

My SELECT query returns 2 rows when both access types are present, so how do I code it to return a single value.
So that if ADP is only present I get ADP,
If SENT is only found I get SENT
**but** if ADP and SENT are both found I only get SENT.

My Table contains lots of fields but in essence looks like this

```
SUA_PERUSER_ID  SUA_ACCESS_TYPE  
      10000000  ADP  
      10000001  SENT  
      10000002  ADP  
      10000002  SENT
```

My query is this

```
SELECT S_USER_ACCESS.SUA_PERUSER_ID, S_USER_ACCESS.SUA_ACCESS_TYPE  
FROM   S_USER_ACCESS  
WHERE  S_USER_ACCESS.SUA_PERUSER_ID = <Client_ID>
```

where the `<client_ID>` is input by the user.

Comment: Could you please provide some additional inforamion? Structure of table, examle of data and expected result

Comment: Please show us the tables and the query you have.

Comment: Please note: while it is a very good practice to qualify column names by their table name, that's not usually done when all you have in a query is a single table. And, for ease of reading, you can use a table alias (which in Oracle does not use the keyword AS; the syntax is `FROM S_USER_ACCESS S` - and then in the other clauses you can say `S.SUA_PERUSER_ID` and `S.SUA_ACCESS_TYPE`. Easier on the eye!

Comment: The most critical part of doing this is knowing the business rule that makes you determine which is the correct value to return if more than one is present. Without that any solution is a guess. It might return data but not necessarily teh correct data.

Answer (score 2):

As Massimo said, you will need to `group by sua_peruser_id` to get only one value. Or, if you need to do this for just one `sua_peruser_id`, you will have a `where` clause (and no need for `group by`).

If you don't want to use the accident of lexicographically `'SENT' > 'ADP'`, you could do something like this (more code, but less chance of bugs):

```
select sua_peruser_id, 
       max(sua_access_type) keep (dense_rank first order by
                                          case sua_access_type when 'SENT' then 1
                                                               when 'ADP'  then 2
                                          end) as sua_access_type
from s_user_access
group by sua_peruser_id
```

An even better solution if you have more than two possible values, `SENT` and `ADP`, is to have these possible values in a separate table, with their priority order in a second column... but perhaps that's overkill in your specific use case.

**Edit** - Still waiting for the OP to clarify the modified requirement. It appears that if both `'SENT'` and `'ADP'` are present, the result should show `'BOTH'` instead of `'SENT'`. This can be best done with aggregate functions `min()` and `max()`. There are two versions - a simpler one if `'SENT'` and `'ADP'` are guaranteed to appear no more than once for each `sua_peruser_id`, and a more complicated one if duplicates are possible. Below I show the more complicated version, which works in the more general case.

```
select sua_peruser_id, 
       case when min(sua_access_type) != max(sua_access_type) then 'BOTH'
            else min(sua_access_type) 
       end  as sua_access_type
from   s_user_access
where  sua_peruser_id = <customer_id>  -- (provided by user)
```

Comment: This is way beyond my sql skills, but wouldn't the fact that when two records are returned the ADP would always satisfy the second case statement and return 2 rather than 1 -RR

Comment: @RayRudd - No, it wouldn't. You will get two rows, one with `SENT, 1` and the other with `ADP, 2`.  From these two, `keep (dense_rank FIRST)` will pick just the row with `SENT, 1`.  And from this one row, `max(sua_access_type)` will be just `SENT` (it's now the max over a single value!)

Comment: Anyway, in your case (if it's not more complicated than you described), Massimo's solution is probably best - it is quite simple, and can be maintained by developers who are not familiar with the `first` and `last` functions. Massimo's solution got my upvote!

Comment: OK to clarify - If the result of the query returns SENT then I want the answer to be SENT, If the result is ADP then I want ADP, if the result returns two rows, then I want  an answer of BOTH. So I get a single answer as an output of the query.

Comment: OK, that is exactly what I did in the added portion of my answer. I also covered the possibility you may have TWO rows both with `SENT` and none with `ADP`. If such duplication is not possible in your base table, you can replace the condition about `min() != max()` with a simpler one, for example `count(*) = 2` ( in the `when` condition of the `case` expression ).

Answer (score 1):

Calling your field as "access_type" and your table "access"and imaging the existence of a field "owner" you can try with this dirty sql

```
select max(access_type) , owner from access group by owner
```

It's a little bit dirty and uses the fact that lexically SENT is > than ADP

**EDIT**
With the need of 3 results it changes a lot:

```
select decode (sum(partial.cnt),1,'ADP',2,'SENT',3,'BOTH') access_type, patial.owner from (
select decode(access_type,'ADP', 1,'SENT',2,0) cnt, access_type, owner from     access ) partial
group by partial.owner
```

The partial subquery translates the access_type into numbers, the outer query decodes the sum of results. 
The constraint is that you should have no more than 2 rows per 'owner'.

Sorry if theres some sql mistake as i don't have an sql console to test right now

Comment: Massimo this works, how much more complicated does it become it I want three 'logical' outcomes. One for SENT, one for ADP, and one for BOTH.

Comment: @RayRudd - What do you mean? Is `BOTH` another possible value in the column, or do you want to return `BOTH` if `SENT` and `ADP` are both present for a `sua_peruser_id`? The two interpretations are very different.

Comment: @RayRudd let me think a little bit

Comment: Posted a proposal

Comment: @mathguy - To expand on your example case statement so that  Case SENT = 1 - Case ADP = 2 and Case SENT & ADP = 3

Comment: @RayRudd - The requirement is not clear to me. You should be able to explain it without reference to any proposed solution. Do you want to show `BOTH` if rows with `ADP` and `SENT` are present in the column, for the same `id`? That is solved differently, not with the solution I proposed for your original problem. Please clarify the requirement (not the solution!)

Comment: @RayRudd -  Just in case, I added a solution if `BOTH` is not in the inputs, but you may want it in the output (when both `ADP` and `SENT` are found in the inputs).

Comment: @RayRudd did you see my solution up ?

Answer (score 0):

If ADP and SENT are two columns in the same table and one of them may be null, use the [`NVL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) function:

`SELECT NVL(SENT, ADP) FROM ....`

The above will evaluate to the value of SENT if SENT is not null. Otherwise, it will evaluate to the value of ADP.

Comment: ADP and SENT are two possible *values* in a column, and sometimes a query for an ID may find both values for that ID. Not sure how that may be interpreted as "two columns."